# Неправильное отображение запросов к базе Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Есть следующий код для получения данных из базы посредством Yii

```
    $query = Task::find()
        ->where([Task::tableName().'.parent_id' => 0]);
    $query->leftJoin(TaskModel::tableName());
    $query->leftJoin(ClientEntity::tableName());
    $query->andWhere([TaskModel::tableName().'.task_id' => Task::tableName().'.id']);
    $query->andWhere([ClientEntity::tableName().'.client_id' => TaskModel::tableName().'.model_id']);

    $rows = $query
        ->offset($pages->offset)
        ->limit($pages->limit)
        ->orderBy([
            Task::tableName().'.status' => SORT_DESC,
            Task::tableName().'.`estimated_date`=0' => SORT_ASC,
            Task::tableName().'.estimated_date' => SORT_ASC
        ])
        ->all();
```

Вроде все соблюдено, но по итогу я получаю

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (`task`.`parent_id`=0) AND (`task_model`.`task_id`='{{%task}}.id') AND (`c' at line 1
```

Пытался записывать названия таблиц в переменные, операторы отдельно ставить в кавычках, но по итогу всегда получаю такую же штуку.

Comment: В сформированном запросе присутствует условие `\`task`.`parent_id`=0`, которое отсутствует в показанном фрагменте кода. И вообще мне кажется, что у Вас в leftJoin немножко отсутствует условие связывания...

Comment: @Akina при инициализации запроса `$query = Task::find()->where([Task::tableName().'.parent_id' => 0]);`

Comment: Ну так покажите ВЕСЬ код формирования запроса, а не обрывок.

Comment: @Akina дополнил код в теме

Comment: 1) Разместите методы в правильном порядке (find..leftjoin..where). 2) Не размещайте условия связывания в секции WHERE. Это мало того что неправильно, так ещё и превратит LEFT JOIN в INNER JOIN (если пройдёт синтаксический контроль, конечно).

Comment: @Akina методы не получится, ибо у меня сложные условия. Да и он правильно их вставляет. А вот с условиями связывания спасибо, тут как раз ошибочка и была

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было просто нормально сделать join'ы (спасибо @Akina)

Ну и, как выяснилось позже, записывать условия для join'ов именно в таком формате. Что бы получалась одна строка, иначе 2 параметр ставится в кавычки, и 2 модели использовать не получается.

```
$query = Task::find()
    ->where([Task::tableName().'.parent_id' => 0]);
$query->leftJoin(TaskModel::tableName(), TaskModel::tableName().'.task_id = ' . Task::tableName().'.id');
$query->leftJoin(ClientEntity::tableName(), ClientEntity::tableName().'.client_id = ' . TaskModel::tableName().'.model_id']);

$rows = $query
    ->offset($pages->offset)
    ->limit($pages->limit)
    ->orderBy([
        Task::tableName().'.status' => SORT_DESC,
        Task::tableName().'.`estimated_date`=0' => SORT_ASC,
        Task::tableName().'.estimated_date' => SORT_ASC
    ])
    ->all();
```